# How to split the values in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, split, angularjs-scope

I have created a scope function like this.

```
$scope.getTotal = function(){
        var total1 = 0;
        var total2 = 0;
        var total3 = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.today.length; i++){
            var ordqt = $scope.today[i]["OrdQ"];
            var ordvval = $scope.today[i]["OrdSV"];
            var resqt = $scope.today[i]["RecQ"];

            total1 = +total1 + +ordqt;
            total2 = +total2 + +ordvval;
            total3 = +total3 + +resqt;

        }
        total = total1+"@"+total2+"@"+total3;
        return total;
    }
```

How can I split the values  from the getTotal function to display here?

```
<td>{{ getTotal() }}<td>
<td>{{ getTotal() }}<td>
<td>{{ getTotal() }}<td>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: how would you like to split it ? , you add 3 values and return the result ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should correct below lines

```
total1 = total1 + ordqt;
total2 = total2 + ordvval;
total3 = total3 + resqt;
```

You could do it by using `ng-repeat`.

```
<td ng-repeat="total in getTotal().split('@') track by $index">
    {{ total }}
</td>
```

Comment: I which format I need to  return the value from getTotal function?  @pankaj

Comment: @Pravin in a string format as you are doing now..which will have values `@` separated

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't join them in the first place:

```
$scope.getTotal = function() {
    // ...
    return {
        total1: total1,
        total2: total2,
        total3: total3
    };
}
```

and

```
<td>{{ getTotal().total1 }}<td>
<td>{{ getTotal().total2 }}<td>
<td>{{ getTotal().total3 }}<td>
```

Or even better, make 3 different functions, computing the 3 different totals, and call each function from the view.

Or even better, make a single function taking the field you want to compute the total for in argument:

```
$scope.getTotal = function(field){
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.today.length; i++){
        var value = $scope.today[i][field];
        total = +total + +value;
    }
    return total;
}
```

and use

```
<td>{{ getTotal('OrdQ') }}<td>
<td>{{ getTotal('OrdSV') }}<td>
<td>{{ getTotal('RecQ') }}<td>
```

Note that your code would be much more readable if you used meaningful names. What do `OrdQ` and `ordqt` mean? Why use `ordqt` sometimes and `OrdQ` sometimes, for the same thing. Why not use something meaningful like, I guess, `orderQuantity`?